# Xpages: Track changes when user updates document from Xpage

Tags: xpages

A business owner of my ticket tracking app in Xpages wants to track every change to the document. If a user opens the doc in edit mode but doesn't change anything, then no tracking. If, however, they open up a document and change one field, I have to capture that.

Here is my solution. When a user edits a doc, I create a "shadow document", which is a "before" vision. When the user saves I am comparing field for field for changes, and then acting appropriately.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A couple unique times I had a use case (with a relatively small amount of fields) where I've copied the pre-edit values into a _viewScope_'d _HashMap_ when the user triggers "edit" mode, then immediately prior to my save event, I do a comparison of current to previous values. This means I can observe exactly what has changed (and when and by whom), where you store that could be anywhere.

Comment: I have been trying to implement this and have really been struggling. If you find an easy way to implement please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another good use case for Java beans. If you create a bean which sits between XPages-UI and Domino back-end document then you can easily track field changes.

Karsten Lehmann wrote a [blog](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/18.03.2011104725KLEDH8.htm) about it some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

... and you could use the OpenNTF Domino API that has functions for exactly this. As far as I remember there is an example of this in the demo database. Not sure if it is also in the [new version of the demo database](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API%20Demo%20Database) - but then you may just need to find an older version (e.g. for milestone 4.5 where I saw this).

/John